# When storing environment specific configuration variables in an AWS service, how do I do so?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I would like to store some connection string variables that vary based upon environment.  How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Store them in parameter store. See [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) for more details.

If you run a separate AWS account per environment (DEV, TEST, ...) then no problems. If you have a single account, you can structure your environment parameters into a hierarchy. See [Organizing Parameters into Hierarchies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-su-organize.html) for more details.